# How can i solve graphprotocol / graph-node 'ServerError(-32000), message: "missing trie node' error

Tags: graphql, subgraph

I lived this problem on Huobi ECO Chain. How can i solve this?

> Feb 23 03:57:05.777 DEBG Found 1 relevant block(s), subgraph_id:
> QmTXfVewLoDqTjj2kT2Fofb1kh8tYr7yHmPjzLJCs2VFzy, component:
> SubgraphInstanceManager > BlockStream
>
> Feb 23 03:57:05.778 DEBG Requesting 0 block(s), subgraph_id:
> QmTXfVewLoDqTjj2kT2Fofb1kh8tYr7yHmPjzLJCs2VFzy, component:
> SubgraphInstanceManager > BlockStream
>
> Feb 23 03:57:05.779 DEBG Processing 1 triggers, subgraph_id:
> QmTXfVewLoDqTjj2kT2Fofb1kh8tYr7yHmPjzLJCs2VFzy, component:
> SubgraphInstanceManager > BlockStream
>
> Feb 23 03:57:05.779 INFO 1 trigger found in this block for this
> subgraph, block_hash:
> 0x33856eb6a0a44fc371890f782163617a57e6834313e334c86e4860f4e6828208,
> block_number: 867157, subgraph_id:
> QmTXfVewLoDqTjj2kT2Fofb1kh8tYr7yHmPjzLJCs2VFzy, component:
> SubgraphInstanceManager
>
> Feb 23 03:57:05.779 DEBG Start processing Ethereum trigger,
> data_source: Factory, handler: handleNewPair, trigger_type: Log,
> address: 0xc32c…b719, signature: PairCreated(indexed address,indexed
> address,address,uint256), runtime_host: 1/1, block_hash:
> 0x33856eb6a0a44fc371890f782163617a57e6834313e334c86e4860f4e6828208,
> block_number: 867157, subgraph_id:
> QmTXfVewLoDqTjj2kT2Fofb1kh8tYr7yHmPjzLJCs2VFzy, component:
> SubgraphInstanceManager
>
> Feb 23 03:57:06.190 DEBG Trying again after eth_call RPC call failed
> (attempt #1) with result Err(Web3Error(Rpc(Error { code:
> ServerError(-32000), message: "missing trie node
> 93640656c6c663ff60b38617452487c3096d863e2ec92756d2fdb4058443c3b7 (path
> )", data: None }))), runtime_host: 1/1, block_hash:
> 0x33856eb6a0a44fc371890f782163617a57e6834313e334c86e4860f4e6828208,
> block_number: 867157, subgraph_id:
> QmTXfVewLoDqTjj2kT2Fofb1kh8tYr7yHmPjzLJCs2VFzy, component:
> SubgraphInstanceManager

Comment: Hello, did you fix this issue?